# What technique has sharelatex used on its web editor?

Tags: jquery, latex, frontend

[image]

I  am not familiar to the front end;
Does the editor use jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

[ShareLaTeX is open source](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2014/02/21/sharelatex-is-now-open-source.html), so you can view the code and install/run it locally and see the code functionality.